# How do I solve the 'TPM Error in read-only firmware' error message on my Chromebook?

Tags: chromebook

I turned on my Chromebook and I got the Chrome OS missing or damaged screen. I pressed tab and it said the recovery reason was- 
'TPM Error in read-only firmware'. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

With the device on at the OS error screen, press and hold Reload + Power until the device shuts off, the backlight flickers, and then shuts off again. Release the keys, wait 5-10 seconds, and then power back on.

Repeat those steps continuously anywhere from 5-30 times and the device will then boot back up normally.

I'm not sure what causes the TPM error, but I've been able to resolve it with the process above every time.